# Parse Ajax Posted JSON data in DelegatingHandler

Tags: .net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

Without going into the details of why I want to do this, here is what I want to do.

Json data is posted using jquery like so:

```
jq.ajax({
    url: 'api/values',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { a: 'hello', b: 'world' }
});
```

In a WebAPI DelegatingHandler, I'd like to parse that content back into Json:

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var data = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    //data is url encoded, I want it as json...
    //???
    //...I'm going to do something with the json string here

    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}
```

Json.NET will do this by the time it gets to the WebAPI method that's going to handle it, so clearly it's doable, I'm just not sure how.

Note that I don't need it to be strongly typed or anything like that - a plain Json string will do.

Comment: The above example is returned as "a=hello&b=world" by request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

Comment: It has to be parsed back to json.